# Deserialize JSON object with array

Tags: c#, json

Why do i get an error when i try to deserialize this JSON:

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "demo",
  "pixeldata" : [
      { "time" : "1", "colour" : "#ff5357" },
      { "time" : "2", "colour" : "#2424ff" },
      { "time" : "3", "colour" : "#ff0d13" },
      { "time" : "4", "colour" : "#f7ff4a" },
      { "time" : "5", "colour" : "#fa24ff" },
      { "time" : "6", "colour" : "#ff3e43" }
  ]
}
```

into these classes:

```
public struct Display
{
    public int id;
    public string name;
    public List<Pixeldata> pixeldata;
}

public struct Pixeldata
{
    public float time;
    public string colour;
}
```

using this:

```
Display MyDisplay = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Display>(json_string);
```

error says:

```
Error converting value "[{ "time" : "1", "colour" : "#ff5357"}, {etc...}]" to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[Pixeldata]'. Path 'pixeldata', line 1, position 313.
```

I've been reading similar QnA's, looking at various examples and they all look like this should work, but it doesn't, what do i do?

---

Update: i used this code to dump my string

```
Debug.Print("JSON DUMP: "+_ServerResponse.data);
```

this is the exact result as it shows in the console

```
JSON DUMP: {"id":1,"name":"demo","pixeldata":"[{ \"time\" : \"1\", \"colour\" : \"#ff5357\"},{ \"time\" : \"2\", \"colour\" : \"#2424ff\"},{ \"time\" : \"3\", \"colour\" : \"#ff0d13\"},{ \"time\" : \"4\", \"colour\" : \"#f7ff4a\"},{ \"time\" : \"5\", \"colour\" : \"#fa24ff\"},{ \"time\" : \"6\", \"colour\" : \"#ff3e43\"}]"}
[0:]
```

Comment: Cannot reproduce the error.

Comment: I am not sure but can you try time column as string or int?

Comment: Seems to work ok here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ua8ZFw. Any further info on inner exception?

Comment: that's the only error i have, this is part of a xamarin project if that makes any difference

Comment: Maybe the JSON you're passing to the deserializer is malformed? Are you sure the `json_string` value is identical to what you posted here?

Comment: it should be, ill try test a few things to make doubly sure, i also just copied in the code from andrew's dotnetfiddle script and that works fine

Comment: updated post with debug dump

Comment: Cannot reproduce.  But you can try the IEnumerable instead of List:       public struct Display
    {
        public int id;
        public string name;
        public IEnumerable<Pixeldata> pixeldata;
    }

Comment: You could try remove any non-visible characters: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ua8ZFw

Comment: tried to removespecialcharacters as you suggest andrew and it still errors, does the update in the post give you any more clues?

Comment: I think perhaps pixeldata is a string rather than an array as it is surrounded by quotes ", try pasting your second json example in here to see: https://jsonlint.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON i was receiving was not properly formatted.

I think it has something to do with how SQL stores JSON.

So i just messed around with decoding the values i got from the database then re-encoded them before sending, and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

"time" is of type string in your json, but you try to deserialize to type float. That won't work.

Update: Apparently, after reading the comments on your questions it would work in *some* implementations of Json.Net, but that might be "version-dependent", and hence might not work in your scenario.

Comment: everything here should be pretty well up to date, i think its a nested encoding issue

Comment: Did you even try to change the type of "time" on your C# side to string? (as was suggested by others)

Comment: yes i tried changing time to string and it doesnt work